# Examine exported binary gpg key

Tags: gpg

The commands `gpg --export` and `gpg --export-secret-keys` can be used to export keys in a binary format.

Is there any command available to examine these exported binary key files? I need to see if the exported files contain some extra fields or any other incompatibility problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gpg --list-packets keyfile.gpg
```

Even possible as

```
gpg --export 0x12345678 | gpg --list-packets
gpg --export-secret-keys 0x12345678 | gpg --list-packets
```

Comment: Follow-up [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121572/export-format-of-gpg) for identifying what format is used.