# Export format of gpg

Tags: gpg

What is the binary *export / import* format used by`gpg` for **public** and **private keys**?

Comment: Is this related to [Extract only the key(s) from GPG exported keypair](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121591/2465)?

Comment: Yes, part of the same effort

Comment: @vonbrand: I spend yesterday reading the man pages, tutorials, articles & blog posts and made absolutely no progress. None of the docs mentioned the export format. Silly me for not going straight to the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is defined in [RfC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) (e.g. section 5.5  Key Material Packet).

Comment: Thank you! There are three leading bytes, but after that the version number, time and algorithm match exactly.