# Extract only the key(s) from GPG exported keypair

Tags: gpg

I have exported public and private keys to file with `gpg --export` and `--export-secret-keys`. When I examine them with `gpg --list-packets`. I can see that the file contains:

- the actual key
- the user ID
- a signature packet

How can I extract only the actual key from the file? I would like end up with a PKCS8 private key file and a *PublicKeyInfo*(?) file that I can use programmatically.

Comment: Is this related to [Export format of gpg](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121572/2465)?

Comment: Yes, part of the same effort. To my understanding the site recommendations are not to ask several questions in one post, so I have separated these as individual questions.

Comment: That is absolutely correct, Eero. The reason for my asking that is that sometimes (many times), even when an effort can (and should!) be broken down into separate questions, having some idea of the overall goal can lead to better answers than looking only at the individual question-parts themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You may remove the passphrase and get the raw key material using `gpgsplit`.